# Unzip the files and rename with zip file name?

Tags: rename, unzip

I need to unzip files using 7zip and rename the unzipped files.

Assume that the zip file is `3457.zip` and it is contains `w.dat` and `q.doc`. I'd like to rename `w.dat` and `q.doc` to `3457.dat` and `3457.doc`.

How can this be achieved using a bat file?